# BETWEEN erro dia 31

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa tarde, pequisei mas não achei a solução, por isso estou pedindo ajuda aqui.
Meu sistema recupera dados lançados entre intervalo de datas usando o BETWEEN.

Usando a query para pegar o invervalo de todos os registros do mês de Maio, ele me retora todos o lançamentos referente a esse mês com execeção dos registros no dia 31 de maio.
`SELECT * FROM financeiro_despesas WHERE data_cadastro BETWEEN 2020-05-1 AND 2020-06-31`

Alguém pode me explicar ? tentei em tabelas diferentes e o mesmo erro aconteceu, se mudar a data dos registros do dia 31 e colocar 30, eles aparecem no select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema na sua query é que faltam aspas nas datas.

Sem aspas é feita uma operação matemática, mas isso não faz com que não traga especificamente o dia 31/05/2020, talvez tenha algo errado com os dados.

De qualquer forma, aqui a query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM financeiro_despesas 
 WHERE data_cadastro BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-06-31'
```

E aqui o exemplo funcionando: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mEdpsvzLp8eTiAjreEHM4L/0

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, tentei no phpmyadmin funcionou, mas no php continua a mesma situação, carrega os dados dos outros dias menos o do dia 31.
```$stmt= $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM financeiro_despesas WHERE data_cadastro BETWEEN ? AND ?"); ```

$DataInicial = "2020-05-01";
$DataFinal = "2020-06-31";

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $DataInicial, $DataFinal);
$stmt->execute();

Comment: Como o Ricardo falou, tente: `$DataInicial = "'2020-05-01'"; $DataFinal = "'2020-06-31'"`

Comment: sim, o que o @anonimo mencionou, ou faça um prepare do parametro antes: `$datainicial= date('YYYY-mm-ddd', strtotime($DataInicial));` e use essa outra variável, mas só pra tirar a dúvida, o campo é de qual tipo na tabela?

Comment: acabei de tentar as duas formas e não funcionou, o campo é datetime. no inicio achei que pudesse ser pq só passo data, mas fiz o teste mudando para outra data e funciona, qualquer data funciona, com execessão se o dia for 31. o exemplo do meu código postei nesse link: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e200b58347fcf53e1c6d66a0eddcea52c39524b7

Comment: se o campo é datetime, faça  um teste com a data assim `'2020-05-01 00:00:00'` e `'2020-06-31 23:59:59'` para vermos se está filtando corretamente

Comment: Desculpa a demora @RicardoPontual, o problema foi corrigido adicionando a hora na data inicial e final. Muito Obrigado

Answer (score -3):

O BETWEEN pega o valor entre datas porém se colocar
"SELECT * FROM financeiro_despesas WHERE data_cadastro BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-06-31'" ele coloca automaticamente 00:00:00, ou seja, não irá computar o dia 31. Tem que colocar
"SELECT * FROM financeiro_despesas WHERE data_cadastro BETWEEN '2020-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-06-31 23:59:59'" aí vai dar certo.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).